# Will upgrade change my desktop settings to defaults?

Tags: upgrade, settings

I am going to upgrade to 16.04. I would like to know that will it change my settings to default settings of all apps or not.

Comment: No, usually will not change it.

Comment: What about new update in compiz and unity? Will any change happen there?

Comment: all these settings are stored in your /home/username folder, and a simple upgrade should not affect it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not, however it all depends on how you go about upgrading.

You can either use the updater (Which will most likely save every setting you have made then add all the new features).

Or completely re-install Ubuntu from a LiveCD and therefor wiping everything.